# setting up rails server on mac to access on ipad

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ipad, webserver, localhost

I have a rails app running on localhost:3000.  I can't access the app on my ipad which is connected tothe same Wifi network (macbookpro-ip-address:3000).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

That's becuase localhost is only accessible to the local machine running the application. `localhost` points at the same machine you're trying to connect from, always. You need to set up your http server to bind to `0.0.0.0` (all ip addresses) or your lan IP.

Comment: You're right, I didn't ask the question properly.  I was unable to access the http server from my ipad via ip.  Of course I wasn't using localhost on the ipad :)

Comment: No you said you were running the rails server on localhost port 3000, which I assumed to mean your laptop. Localhost on your laptop points at your laptop, no other machine on the network will be able to get to it. You need to start your web server on your macbook's ip address, not localhost. Then your iPad will be able to access it. Alternatively, you can have your web server bind to 0.0.0.0 as I mentioned above, and it'll bind to every IP on the machine.

Comment: You can use port forwarding on your router settings to route traffic coming to your ip to a local gateway:3000. Check out my solution at http://serverfault.com/questions/229441/how-do-i-access-a-local-web-server-on-my-laptop-from-another-computer/455945#455945

Comment: To an internal IP yes, but not localhost. Localhost only exists on the local machine, each machine has localhost point at that machine, not the other machine. Therefore, if you want to forward a port, that's fine, but you'll need to listen on your LAN IP address (i.e., 192.168.0.50 or whatever it may be). `0.0.0.0` is a dynamic range meaning listen on all IPs on all interfaces. Probably ok unless you have specific reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I changed the wifi network I was connected to.  I was then able to access my rails app via ip from any 3rd party device including ipad.

Apparently, the wifi network I was originally connected to wasn't allowing access to a machines's http server via its ip.  Wish I knew more about networking to understand why...

Comment: besides chaning network, what would be the proper solution?